# Find all jQuery scope stuff

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

As we all know jQuery scope contains the namespace for all jQuery plugins. Is there any way to list all jQuery loaded stuff in jQuery scope? The best example of my question is phpinfo() in PHP, it lists all loaded stuff of PHP.

Comment: `for(var i in $.fn) console.log($.fn[i])` or `Object.keys($.fn)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be okay

```
for (var plugin in $.fn) {
  if ($.fn.hasOwnProperty(plugin)) {
    console.log(plugin);
  }
}
```

---

If es5 is supported, you can use

```
var plugins = Object.keys($.fn).sort().join(", ");
console.log(plugins);
```

I think this produces the nicest output

Comment: thanks, is there any jQuery function available to find jQuery version

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(obj, function(key, value) {
  console.log(key + ": " + value);
});
```